# Настройка доступа к сайту только с использованием VPN (OpenVPN)

Tags: apache2, vpn, openvpn, nextcloud

На удалённом сервере работает Nextcloud, к нему нужно настроить доступ только когда подключён к VPN (OpenVPN) которий установлен на этом же сервере. Подскажите пожалуйста как это правильно сделать, только знакомлюсь с настройкой сети на серверах. Спасибо